# MAX Function in SQL Returning Not the Max Value

Tags: sql, duplicates, max

I've run a MAX() data pull thousands of times, and for some reason this query is returning a couple rows instead of 1 row based on the MAX value of the column in the MAX function.

For example my data looks something like:

```
Max(x) |  date       |  level_1   
4      |  2018-01-07 |  fer 
7      |  2018-01-07 |  fer
```

When it should look like:

```
Max(x) |  date       |  level_1   
  7    |  2018-01-07 |  fer
```

Below is my query edited for simplicity. Am I missing something? If not likely, maybe the data has different formats between rows?

```
SELECT 
    MAX(X) as max_x,
    date,
    level_1,
FROM
    table 
WHERE 
    date = '2018-01-07'
    and level_1 ='abc'
GROUP BY date,
    level_1
```

Comment: Your sample results and query are different.  That makes it hard for other people to understand your query and what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example results, you have issues in your data.  Two things come to mind:

- The `A` or `B` columns have values that look the same but are different (the more likely problem).
- You have additional keys in the `GROUP BY` that are not in the `SELECT` (possible, given the discrepancy between the results and the query).

The most likely cause are leading or trailing spaces.  You can remove them using the appropriate `TRIM()` or `REPLACE()` function in your database.

Two other possible causes are hidden characters or characters that look alike but are different (such as 1 and lower case L or 0 and upper case o).